# How to move vim cursor actually to the end of line ( word )?

Tags: vim, editor, text-cursor

I am new to vim. I have set up my `.vimrc` to change the cursor's shape in different modes.
When I use `$` or `e` in Normal mode the cursor jumps to the position per-character of the end of line or end of word

For example, let `|` represent the cursor's position:

Before I press '$'...

```
|alonglonglineofword
```

After I press '$'...

```
alonglonglineofwor|d
```

Before press `e`...

```
|aword
```

After press `e`...

```
awor|d
```

I wonder if this is caused by my cursor's shape setting. [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31201582/vimrc) is link to my `.vimrc`.

Comment: For future reference it is not necessary (or recommended) to type `</br>` when you want a line break in markdown. Here's a link to the markdown help. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What did you change your cursor to? Normally when you get to the end of the word you have to press `a` to insert after the word? Is this the case? If it is the problem is with the cursor.

Comment: i want to change my cursor to the end of specify word and add more code,so i use `e` to navigate cursor,but it just move to the position infront of which i expect to.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like standard vim behavior. The cursor in normal mode is neither before nor after a given character. It is actually on top of a character and you, the user, decide whether you want to edit before or after that character. For instance, if your cursor is here

```
|alonglonglineofword
```

and you want it to be here

```
alonglonglineofword|
```

to insert some more code, type `A` in normal mode to insert at the end of the line. Alternatively you can type `$a` to go to the end of the line and insert after the cursor position. Likewise if your cursor is here

```
|aword
```

and you want it to be here...

```
aword|
```

You can type `ea` to "append" text after the end of the word. To check and see if it's standard vim behavior that's troubling you or your `.vimrc` you can start vim with `vim -N -u NONE` to bypass your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have never seen the behavior you describe. Seems likely that it could be your changes to the .vimrc file. Suggest you mv that .vimrc out of the way and get yourself a new session to compare the $/e navigation behavior against the default. Also, check the second to the last line for what appears to be a typo "cursor_shape bolck":

```
au VimLeave * silent execute "!gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/cursor_shape bolck"
```